# Thickbox redirect to homepage

Tags: thickbox

I want to close my tickbox after the necessary change are made to the DB.

I am using the `keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true` in the begining of my link.

When done, I am redirecting to a page but it redirects in the thickbox. 
How can I make the thickbox disappear and redirect to another page?

Thanks!!

Comment: i'm designing in .asp